# window.history.back() reloads the page in Internet Explorer when inside of an iframe?

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, back, browser-history

I'm noticing a strange behavior with Internet Explorer when my page is inside of an iframe. It seems that the iframe reloads itself when calling window.history.back(), even though only the hash in the URL should be changing. When the page is not inside of an iframe, it behaves properly and doesn't reload the page. Any idea why this is happening and how to prevent it?

I created a fiddle that will demonstrate this in IE9:

http://jsfiddle.net/peh96/5/

jsfiddle uses an iframe, so the behavior will be the iframe behavior.  Clicking '#foo' and '#bar' will change the hash in the URL.  Now clicking the 'BACK' link will trigger window.history.back(). Notice that the timestamp changes when you do that, indicating that the page is reloading.

Alternatively, if you load the iframe directly:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/peh96/5/show/

you'll notice that the timestamp doesn't change when click 'BACK'.

This is an IE issue only, as Chrome and Firefox is consistent whether inside of an iframe or not.

Any idea how to prevent this reload?

Comment: We are also very bothered by this bug :(

Comment: @Blackbird, what is the workaround that you chose to solve this problem?

Comment: none, unfortunately :( What about you?

Comment: Nothing yet. I'm thinking about building my own history stack and using it instead of window.history.back(). It's a bit ugly, but I don't know any way around it for IE.

Comment: I have the same problem, seems to occur for IE > 8

Comment: @JohnnyO did you find any solution to this reload issue in IE?? please reply what did you finally used to avoid this.

Comment: @Yoda, I never found a solution to this in IE9, but this is no longer broken in IE 11.  I'm not sure about IE 10.

Comment: @JohnnyO cheers for replying back.

Answer (score 2):

Well, when I choose *Back* command from context menu, it does the same. In IE10 you can use [HTML5 State Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh771459.aspx). I'm afraid in IE9 you must track hash history and than change it like this:

```
document.getElementById('back').addEventListener('click', function () {
    window.location.hash = 'abc';
}, false);
```

**Edit**

And what about this?
When you call `javascript:window.top.location.hash='bar'`, you can catch `onhashchange` event in parent window and then call `scrollTo` in iframe. But this works only in the same domain.

Comment: Thank you Václav. But I believe that adds another state into the history stack, is that correct?  So while it will work, it breaks the back/forward states.

Comment: That's true. I will try to figure out another solution.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused, but it looks like http://jsfiddle.net/peh96/5/ shows the example in quirks mode which may couse browser history ignores # links. When I open http://fiddle.jshell.net/peh96/5/show/, it works as expected. Of course you have to update time when `onhashchange` occurs. Check my code: http://jsfiddle.net/ZGqHF/show/

Comment: Hi Václav, you may have misread my question.  The problem occurs when inside of an iframe.  As soon as you take your window outside of the iframe (which is what you're doing), IE behaves properly.  I need a solution to prevent page load when going 'back' in an iframe.

Comment: Oh, my fault, sorry. I use IE10 and it works there. In IE9 it behaves like you described. I originally thought the problem is elsewhere. It looks like it is a bug in IE9 and older.

Comment: Hi Václav, I can't mark this as the answer, but you get the bounty for trying.  Thank you for that.  I'm going to conclude that there's no solution for this.